# Compile error creating a DSL with macros in Elixir

Tags: macros, elixir, dsl

I'm facing a weird problem that is making me nuts.

I'm trying to build a DSL like this:

```
amazon_query do
  list "Items", "//Items/Items" do 
      field :asin, "./ASIN/text()", :string
      field :detail_page, "./DetailPage/text()", :string
    end
end
```

I'm following a similar example of the book Metaprogramming Elixir by Chris McCord, which makes a DSL to parse HTML tags. The example uses an AgentServer to save State.

So my current macros are:

```
defmacro amazon_query(do: inner) do
    quote do
      {:ok, var!(buffer, __MODULE__)} = start_buffer([])
      unquote(inner)
      result = get_result(var!(buffer, __MODULE__))
      stop_buffer(var!(buffer, __MODULE__))
      result
    end
 end



defmacro list(name, xpath, do: inner) do
    quote do
      unquote(inner)

      element_sigil = unquote(xpath)
      element_name = unquote(name)
      element =[{String.to_atom(element_name), ~x(#{element_sigil})l}]

      put_buffer var!(buffer, __MODULE__), element
    end
  end

  defmacro field(name, xpath, :string) when is_atom(name) do
    quote do
      element = { unquote(name), ~x(#{unquote(xpath)})s }         
     put_buffer(var!(buffer, __MODULE__), element) # This line raises the error 
    end
  end
```

And I have this test:

```
 test "Field and element are processed" do
    query =
      amazon_query do
        list "Items", "//Items/Items" do
          field(:asin, "./ASIN/text()", :string)
          field(:detail_page, "./DetailPage/text()", :string)
        end
      end

    assert query == []
  end
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:

```
== Compilation error in file test/get_amazon_query_generator_test.exs ==
** (CompileError) test/get_amazon_query_generator_test.exs:45: expected "buffer" (context GetAmazon.Xml.QueryGeneratorTests) to expand to an existing variable or be part of a match
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.var!/2
    test/get_amazon_query_generator_test.exs:45: GetAmazon.Xml.QueryGeneratorTests."test Field is processed"/1
    (get_amazon) expanding macro: GetAmazon.Xml.QueryGenerator.field/3
    test/get_amazon_query_generator_test.exs:45: GetAmazon.Xml.QueryGeneratorTests."test Field is processed"/1
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:677: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:201: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you reduce your original code to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That would help us find the problem faster.

Comment: I'm not in front of my code right now, and trying to reproduce the error on another computer has ended with a working example. I will check original code and provide a better case if it is still not working.

Comment: Nevermind. The problem was in the tests file. All is working now. Thanks for your help.